# Angular 2 - Assign value to checkbox using reactive form

Tags: angular

I'm trying to assign a value to a checkbox when checked and nothing (or `false`) when unchecked:

```
<input type="checkbox" [value]="key" [formControlName]="variable"/>
```

This doesn't work and the values are either `true` or `false`. Is it possible to assign a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="$event.target.checked ? formGroupName.controls['variable'].setValue(key) : formGroupName.controls['variable'].setValue()" [formControlName]="variable"/>
```